# Where to place 'return false;' in a jQuery function to correct page jumping issue

Tags: jquery, return

Initially I was looking for an answer to show/hide a page jumping issue.
Having found an answer here: [link with href="#" scrolls page to top when used with jquery slidetoggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024342/link-with-href-scrolls-page-to-top-when-used-with-jquery-slidetoggle), I need to understand where to put `return false` in the following code:

```
toggleDetail : function(obj) {
    $(obj).parent().parent().next().toggleClass('hide');
    $(obj).text() == 'Show' ? $(obj).text('Hide') : $(obj).text('Show');
},
```

and here's my call to the show/hide. The 'href="javascript:void(0);"' worked in stopping the page jumping, do I still need the 'return false'?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="VSASearch.toggleDetail(this)">Show</a>
```

I tried adding 'return false' to the end of each `$(obj)` line before the semi-colon, but that was not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
toggleDetail : function(obj) {
    $(obj).parent().parent().next().toggleClass('hide');
    $(obj).text() == 'Show' ? $(obj).text('Hide') : $(obj).text('Show');
    return false;
},
```

Comment: Amazing.... the answers are blazing fast. StackOverflow is such a wealth of excellent information and a community so giving of help.

Adding "return false" on it's own line works perfectly.

Thank you Glennular and GenericTypeTea. 
I like the idea of having as much as i can in the script file rather than on the page so i'll reside there.

thank you.

Comment: @Caroline, that's OK, just don't tell our bosses.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to return false on the onclick handler. If onclick returns false, then the postback/page reload will be stopped.

```
<a href="#" onclick="VSASearch.toggleDetail(this);return false;" />
```

Or you can return the result of your functions as follows:

```
toggleDetail : function(obj) {
    $(obj).parent().parent().next().toggleClass('hide');
    $(obj).text() == 'Show' ? $(obj).text('Hide') : $(obj).text('Show');
    return false;
},
```

with

```
<a href="#" onclick="return VSASearch.toggleDetail(this);" />
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to return false from the onclick hander

```
<a onclick="VSASearch.toggleDetail(this); return false">Show</a>
```

Better yet, use unobtrusive javascript and assign event handler in the $() function:

```
<a id="show">Show</a>

....

$(function() {
 ....
 $("#show").click = function() {
     VSASearch.toggleDetail(this);
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think an anchor tag without an href will validate will it? Just need to stick in a #.

Comment: I don't know for sure. I just assumed you always needed an href, I was asking you the question =D

Comment: Yep, you're right, href is optional! http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp. You learn something new every day.