# stop scrolling to top after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop a web page from scrolling to the top when a link is clicked that triggers javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601933/how-do-i-stop-a-web-page-from-scrolling-to-the-top-when-a-link-is-clicked-that-t)

my browser scrolls to top after ajax request then i use

```
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#loadMore').offset().top }, 2000);
```

to scroll back to my div. 
is there a way i stop it from scrolling to top from the beginning

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to scroll to top only on the first Ajax request, and not on subsequent requests?

Comment: Can you show the code where it triggers the ajax call?

Comment: I don't want it to scroll to top,

Comment: i am calling a webmethod via JSON

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you should add `return false` to the end of your ajax call function. Or to the end of your inline call:

```
<a href="#" onclick="someAjaxCall(); return false">Link</a>
```

Comment: the request adds # to my URL, why?!!

Comment: you set it as `href` attribute to your link or it is default behavior. Show your code to understand what is going on.

Comment: you should `return false` to prevent scrolling.

Comment: it doesn't work after using return false :S

Comment: It works if you put it in right place. But no one see your code and no one can say where did you put `return false`

Comment: If you don't want the # appended, you can use a span instead of an href and attach the onclick to the span.  That's how we do it in our applications that are negatively affected by the # in the url.

Comment: @fl00r hey man thanx allot :) it helped like a charm :D i am done with today's tasks then ;)

Comment: come on.. just remove # and that's it... (it should look like href="")

Comment: I tried adding return false to all my ajax, but it never worked.  Instead, I changed all <a> to <span> because "#" is causing browser to jump to the top as mentioned by user Miroo below

Comment: Changing the 'a' to a 'span' worked. Thanks @AmyAnuszewski

Answer (score 9):

if you are calling the ajax via anchor click, try this:

```
<a id="clicker" href="#">Click here to do ajax</a>

$('#clicker').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.get("/myurl/") })
```

Answer (score 5):

Attach the event handler with jQuery (not with the onclick attribute) and remove the href attribute altogether. The problem is that the browser is navigating when the link is clicked. I see this happen alot when onclick is used and there is an error in your event handler before preventing the default.

Another way to fix it for sure is to not use an <a> but rather a <span>.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* AJAX stuff here */
$('html, body').stop();
```

Comment: the request adds # to the URL, that cause the scrolling to top