# AngularJS disable scrolling to top when $http request completes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple `$http` function in my Angular app that fetches/updates some data on the view when the user clicks a button. Here is the function:

```
function getData() {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/some_endpoint.json',
        params: params
    }).then(function(resp){
        if(resp && resp.data) {
            $scope.data = resp.data;
            // Do some other stuff here
        }
    });
}
```

I've noticed that whenever this function is called, the page scrolls back to the top. I want to know how to prevent this undesirable behavior.

I've already tried all the solutions proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530572/angularjs-how-to-disable-auto-scroll-to-top-of-my-page), but none of them have any effect. Additionally, I'd like to avoid having my `$http` function or its wrapper function `getData` return `false`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449833/stop-scrolling-to-top-after-ajax-request) as that would prevent me from chaining additional promise functions to it.

Comment: Could you give the view/HTML code as well?

Comment: It's just a button with an `ng-click` attribute on it that updates a chart. I don't think the HTML is relevant at all. For what it's worth, I have this "problem" with every single `$http` call in the entire app.