# href="#" is forcing the page to reposition itself to the top - how can I stop this?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop a web page from scrolling to the top when a link is clicked that triggers javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601933/how-do-i-stop-a-web-page-from-scrolling-to-the-top-when-a-link-is-clicked-that-tr)

When I click on a date of a jQuery datepicker on my web page, my page repositions itself to the top because the date on the datepicker has an `href="#"` attribute.

It seems that whenever I click an `<a>` element that has `href="#"` then my page reorientates iteself to display from the top of the page. This is pretty annoying because the user is having to cope with the page moving about and may even have to scroll just to see the part of the page they were using before they clicked. Can anyone tell me how I can stop this from happening?

I can take the `href` attribute from some of my links, but jQuery widgets often have them in.

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually when a link has `href="#"`, it's because it's supposed to do something *other* than navigating (the exception being "To the top" links seen on some long pages...). The "other thing" they're doing is usually handled via JavaScript, and to make sure that they don't continue to their default handler (i.e. navigate) the JS handler should **return false**.

If you make sure that all your click handlers **return false**, you won't have this problem anymore.

If you're using jQuery to hook up your events, you could also call `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` on the first argument to the click handler function. This will do it on it's own in most browsers, but you should still return false for compatibility.

```
$('.someLink').click(function(ev) {
    // do your thing

    // Prevent the click from being handled.
    ev.preventDefault();
    // Prevent the event from propagating through the DOM tree (bubbling)
    ev.stopPropagation();
    // Return false, for compatibility reasons
    return false;
});
```

Note: If there are click handlers in some library you're using that *doesn't* return false, you can always wrap it in a handler function of your own that does. But I'd consider abandoning that library...

Comment: +1 - for going into details for the OP, good answer.

Comment: +1 - for teaching me a thing or two!

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by doing this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work and avoid dealing with the url hash:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Click me</a>
```

Comment: I always do this, anything wrong in it ?

Answer (score 1):

When using jQuery you can take advantage of the `event.preventDefault()` function such as:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Will not jump to top of page after alert');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: It is recommended to also `return false`, to handle cross-browser compatibility. Furthermore, it should be noted that this event will still propagate to parent elements in the DOM tree, so to really stop everything you should also add `event.stopPropagation()`. (And since `event` is a keyword in javascript, it's better to call the variable something else - I usually end up with `ev`...)

Comment: You don't need a js library to do this -1.

Comment: @Tomas Lycken thanks for your comments Tomas I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: @JonH - The OP is already making use of jQuery

Comment: @Curt - you are right i got rid of the downvote sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault` method of the event object to avoid this or just return false from the click handler.

```
$("a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just not use `href="#"` and set `cursor: pointer;` in css

Comment: This is not a bad solution, actually - so why the downvote?

Comment: It has the downside, that the link is no longer part of the tab event, and thus very hard to identify for eg. visualy impaired.

Answer (score 0):

write some jQuery like this

`jQuery('a[href=#]').attr('href','javascript:void(null);');`

Comment: You don't need to use a js library to avoid this -1.

Comment: got rid of -1 as OP is using jquery