# HTML Link Do Nothing If Already On Page

Tags: html

If I am on a page and click the respective link in the navigation bar, how can I *prevent the link from reloading the page* (i.e. do nothing) when I am currently at that location? I still want the link to function, but only do nothing when I am already on that page.

Comment: is this vanilla JS, Jquery, angularJS, angular?

Comment: @rjustin I would prefer to use just html if at all possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Links that do nothing when you are on the page they link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119401/html-links-that-do-nothing-when-you-are-on-the-page-they-link-to)

Comment: If its just html, put  a # in the href="#" on the page thats linking. If there is no scripting you will always know what page you are on.

Comment: not possible with just html... you have to manipulate the DOM with some sort of script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by far not the "best" way to do it I'm sure, but can be accomplished with Javascript/JQuery as I've done in the past when required in a mobile web application.

```
var url = window.location.pathname,
urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
$('a').each(function(){
    if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))) {
        $(this).click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
```

If PHP is an option you could try something like this:

```
\\Run this at top of page
<?php

        function getPageName()
        {
            $filename = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
            $breakfile = Explode('/', $filename);
            $pfile = $breakfile[count($breakfile) - 1];

            return $pfile;
        }

    ?>

\\Modify HTML links to something like this    
    <?php if(getPageName() == 'FILENAME.html'){ ?>

        \\Nav Link Here
        <a href="#" >NAV TITLE</a>


    <?php }else{ ?>


    <a href="FILENAME.html" >NAV TITLE</a>


    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is PHP an option?