# jQuery - validation result is different from JS Fiddle demo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a very weird issue where the code of my working files doesn't work when the same code on my JS Fiddle works fine.

All I am doing is checking whether either username or password field is submitted blank.
For some reason, my working platform code doesn't pick up any input value.

I've gone through number of times, making sure that I am on same code environment
but everything is identical. I don't know where to take it from here.

```
(function($){
    $('#signIn_1').click(function () {  

        var username = $('#username_1').val();
        var password = $('#password_1').val();

        if ( username === '' || password === '' ) {
            $('.fa-user').removeClass('success').addClass('fail');  
        } else {
            $('.fa-user').removeClass('fail').addClass('success');      
        }

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Is my if statement violating any rules that might result in inconsistency?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/CgLKa/11/)

Comment: you would want to trim username and password before checking for equality in 'if'

Comment: Thanks. I originally had `trim` and here tested without it. Both did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `<form>` element is submitting, thus reloading the page. I recommend modifying the form's `submit` event rather than giving the button a `click` event, as forms are usually **but not necessarily** triggered by clicking the button. Also, [`return false` is not a good way of disabling behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971284/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false-no-jquery).

Example:

```
(function($){
    $('#form_1').submit(function (event) {
        var username = $('#username_1').val();
        var password = $('#password_1').val();
        if ( username === '' || password === '' ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.fa-user').removeClass('success').addClass('fail');
        }
        else {
            $('.fa-user').removeClass('fail').addClass('success');      
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RyanJW/VqwNw/1/

Answer (score 1):

check this
use `return false` to stop execution

```
(function($){
    $('#signIn_1').click(function () {  

        var username = $('#username_1').val();
        var password = $('#password_1').val();

        if ( $.trim(username) === '' || $.trim(password) === '' ) {
            $('.fa-user').removeClass('success').addClass('fail');  
            return false;
        } else {
            $('.fa-user').removeClass('fail').addClass('success');      
        }

    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CgLKa/13/)