# jQuery e.preventDefault not working only on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i have problem with preventing section jumping on button click. My code is:

Script:

```
    $('.read-more').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".active").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
        var target = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
        $("#" + target).show().siblings("div").hide();
        $(this).closest("article").find(".read-more").each(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
        $(this).closest("article").find(".arrow-marker").each(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
        return false
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <article class="service">
        <a href="#" class="read-more" data-toggle="expand1"></a>
        <button class="read-more" data-toggle="expand1">Read More</button>
        <span class="arrow-marker"></span>
    </article>
    <article class="service">
        <a href="#" class="read-more" data-toggle="expand2"></a>
        <button class="read-more" data-toggle="expand2">Read More</button>
        <span class="arrow-marker"></span>
    </article>
    <article class="service">
        <a href="#" class="read-more" data-toggle="expand3"></a>
        <button class="read-more" data-toggle="expand3">Read More</button>
        <span class="arrow-marker"></span>
    </article>
    <article class="service">
        <a href="#" class="read-more" data-toggle="expand4"></a>
        <button class="read-more" data-toggle="expand4">Read More</button>
        <span class="arrow-marker"></span>
    </article>

    <div id="expand1"></div>
    <div id="expand2"></div>
    <div id="expand3"></div>
    <div id="expand4"></div>
```

The basic thing about this script is toggling 4 tabs and related classes. I need  and  to do the same thing.

I must say, it works fine, only first click of any tab jumps to top of page, and every click after that works fine. Can you find what is wrong with the code? I know there's probably better solution to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you put your script within a document ready event handler? http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: remove e.preventDefault(); and let me know if you are still facing the issue

Comment: yes, it's in $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: Then it should work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/aku0djcm/

Comment: also, tried, without e.prevent and i still got problem.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: And one more [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5jux8y4/1/) with simplified code.

Comment: You can take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21230612/873650

Comment: Yes, fiddles working fine, i guess it's some other part of code that interferes with this one.

Comment: @voodoosnares if your code doesn't have thousands of lines, you can create fiddle with full code, because otherwise it's impossible to figure out what is wrong with you code.

Comment: @Regent it's a big code, very big. I think that i found solution. Just checking.

Comment: Can you update me your fiddle with code to close curent div? e.g. click on item 1 again, closes item 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure it will help, but try using .on like so:

```
$('body').on('click', '.read-more', function(){});
```

Comment: Nope, it make it jump to top of page now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.read-more').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".active").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
        var target = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
        $("#" + target).show().siblings("div").hide();
        $(this).closest("article").find(".read-more").each(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
        $(this).closest("article").find(".arrow-marker").each(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
        return false
    });
 });
</script>


   <article class="service">
        <a href="#" class="read-more" data-toggle="expand1"></a>
        <button class="read-more" data-toggle="expand1">Read More</button>
        <span class="arrow-marker"></span>
    </article>
    <article class="service">
        <a href="#" class="read-more" data-toggle="expand2"></a>
        <button class="read-more" data-toggle="expand2">Read More</button>
        <span class="arrow-marker"></span>
    </article>
    <article class="service">
        <a href="#" class="read-more" data-toggle="expand3"></a>
        <button class="read-more" data-toggle="expand3">Read More</button>
        <span class="arrow-marker"></span>
    </article>
    <article class="service">
        <a href="#" class="read-more" data-toggle="expand4"></a>
        <button class="read-more" data-toggle="expand4">Read More</button>
        <span class="arrow-marker"></span>
    </article>

    <div id="expand1">A Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum </div>
    <div style="clear:both; height:20px;"></div>
    <div id="expand2" style="display:none">B Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</div>
    <div style="clear:both; height:20px;"></div>
    <div id="expand3" style="display:none">C Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
    <div style="clear:both; height:20px;"></div>
    <div id="expand4" style="display:none">D Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/anujsoft/rb7o8xxu/

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I found solution, the problem was in class .active. Bootstrap carousel had class active, i have targeted all active classes on page... On Click, carousel disappeared and that caused jumping... stupid me.

Thank guys for help!!!