# Jquery onClick-event for submit form in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, form-submit

I have a js-code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#form #submitForm', function(e){
    $('#form').submit();
    return false;
});


$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e){
    // ajax request on submit form

    return false;
});
```

where `#form` is the id of form, `#submitForm` is the id of submit-button inside this form.

I use `.on()` because of fact that my form is dynamically generated by ajax requests on submit.

Some people with Google Chrome on Win7 complaints about this isn't working and by pressing `#submitForm` just redirect to "form action"-url occurs.

I have Google Chrome on Win7 and it's working perfectly.

Want do I missing or did wrong?

Comment: why return else after submit;

Comment: I don't see any errors in this code.

Comment: where is the "#informer" you're talking about anyway?

Comment: You stop submit event with return false. So it does nothing, as expected. You have to put an Ajax post request to submit the form without refreshing, because right now, it just does nothing.

Comment: By the way, you pass an argument "e" in the function that you don't use in the function, so you can simply remove it.

Comment: That is right, but it didn't solve the problem. I know it should working and it is works for me, but someone have this problem and i don't know why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, this will redirect to the url action. If you dont want to redirect, you have to create an ajax that "submit " the form

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to stop the default behaviour of form when submit button is pressed.

Change your code to this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e){
  // ajax request on submit form
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropogation();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I think `return false;` in jquery means both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: well i am not really sure about the reliability of using return false.. see this question for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971284/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false-no-jquery