# Javascript DOM Onclick event trigger for single element

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

Basically ive got a page, the code:

```
<body>
    <div onclick="alert('You clicked ' + this.tagName)">
       <h1 onclick="alert('You Clicked ' + this.tagName)">Click Me</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is not my exact script but i rebuilt it for demonstrational purposes, when I click on the `H1` it alerts like it should but when I close the alert box the `DIV` comes up , I have tried another way round it where I had

```
document.addEventListener('click' , function(e){
     var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
     alert('You Clicked ' + target.tagName);
});
```

This didn't work on all Elements of the page for some elements on the page for a weird reason is the a reason for this, am I missing something?

Comment: Use `return false` in event handler at the end

Comment: i also use that sorry i forgot to put that it doesnt stop any more

Comment: i made a fiddle for you check it out and let  me know  is this what you want  http://jsfiddle.net/9f8mfpvq/1/

Comment: Close document.addEventListener(); You are missing ')'  I hope

Comment: See [*MDN:Event.stopPropagation()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Comment: return false is not really the correct way, to stop event propagation as per RobG and Shailendra Sharma's suggestions is definitely the way to go. To read more about it, please [view this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971284/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false-no-jquery) and [this one as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because After an event triggers on the deepest possible element, it then triggers on parents in nesting order

You need to stop event propagation in your case

```
 <body>
        <div onclick="alert('You clicked ' + this.tagName)">
           <h1 onclick="alert('You Clicked ' + this.tagName);event.stopPropagation();">Click Me</h1>
            xcxc
        </div>
    </body>
```

here the fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/9f8mfpvq/1/

Comment: Thanks Ive marked it as the Answer, I cant believe i didnt realise that, nooby mistakes