# Ajax request to server from html page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

I made a server on NodeJs using module Express. Now I want to implement a request from html page with `$.ajax` by clicking a button. I want to get data from server in json format or in text format, it doesnt matter, but it doesn't work. Why?

And plus why does ajax request reload the html page while it shouldn't?

 
Server part:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();
var url = require("url");
app.get('/scrape', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Someone made request");
    url = 'http://spun.fkpkzs.ru/Level/Gorny';
    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log("Inside request");
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var date, waterlevel;
            var json = {
                time: "",
                waterlevel: ""
            };
            json.time = $("#waterleveltable td.timestampvalue").first().text()
            json.waterlevel = $("#waterleveltable td.value").first().text()
            res.send(json);
            console.log(json);
        }
    })
})
app.listen('8081')
console.log('Server started on port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

This is my hmlt request:

```
<form>
    <!--       button for sending a request to server-->
    <button id="button12">Scrape water height</button>
</form>
<div id="response21">
    Print
    <!--     div for displaying the response from server   -->
</div>
<p id="p1">___!</p>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button12").click(function () {
            console.log("Get sent.")
                // Json request    
            $.get("http://localhost:8081/scrape", function (data) 
            {
                console.log("Data recieved" + data);
                $("#response21")
                    .append("Time: " + data.time)
                    .append("Waterlevel: " + data.waterlevel);
            }, "json");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is your HTML page also loaded on `localhost:8081`?

Comment: I just opening HTML page in my browser(Chrome)

Comment: yes, and what is the address in your browser?

Comment: Why not just change the button into a link instead. The fact that its wrapped around form tags makes it behave like a regular form action button!

Comment: I fixed issuie with reload added  `event.preventDefault()` in `onclick `function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the fact that your button is inside a form, the default action of clicking the button will be to load a new page. This is what causes the reload of your page.

The simplest thing you can do is a `return false` at the end of the click handler callback so that to prevent the reload of the page.

Comment: Be wary; `return false;` and `event.preventDefault()` behave differently. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971284/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false-no-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: Right @StephenP , `event.preventDefault()` would be more accurate in this case.

Comment: Thanks, It helped :)