# How does "#" (hash mark, number sign) close a modal box?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I recently read this article about creating a pure CSS modal box:

- [Creating a modal window with HTML5 & CSS3](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/gnerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/)

I've tested the code and it works great. I'm using it for my site's contact and register/log-in pages.

There is one part of the code I haven't fully grasped.

How does this...

```
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
```

...*close the box?*

There is nothing in the CSS that hides or removes an element with a `close` class, nor any similar function targeting `href`, `#close` or `title`. It's simply that one line of code by itself, and when the use clicks on it, the modal window closes (neatly and elegantly, I might add).

It's clear that the "close" text doesn't matter. The text could be anything and the function works. But if "#" is removed, the styling fails, but the window still closes.

So what's so special about "#"?

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box</h2>
    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you click on href="#openModal", it finds the fragment with id="openModal" and puts the focus on it. Changing its state. The css .modalDialog:target comes into action making the modal visible with opacity:1.

When you click on href="#close", it tries to find fragment id="close", which is not present. It also removes focus from any other fragment, making modalDialog loose focus. So nothing remains in focus. and modal closes.

Comment: Good answer - this is the key to way it works. Just for clarity, the key is that it removes the target state, not the focus

Comment: So how would you close this modal with javascript? `document.getElementById('close').click();` won't work.

Comment: just do window.location.hash=''. That should remove the target state.

Answer (score 7):

The hash mark `#` matters for two reasons.

- provides the `target` as an internal location.
- allows the `target` to change, thereby allowing the modal to close, via CSS.

By definition, the character string that follows the `#` represents the URL fragment.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href)

> A URL fragment is a name preceded by a hash mark (#), which specifies an internal target location (an ID) within the current document.

Though its commonly re-purposed when used with scripts <sup>[1]</sup>, when used by itself - the hash mark without a **name** represents an **empty fragment identifier** (exhibiting the scroll to top behaviour).

While navigating to a fragment, the algorithm involved can be read about in the [HTML5 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-indicated-part-of-the-document) which includes a reference to this behaviour.

> If **fragid** is the empty string, then the indicated part of the document is the top of the document.

**Context**

If just the `#` mark is used, when the modal is closed, we will observe a scroll top. Provided the contents of the page exceed the viewport and the modal is opened somewhere halfway down.

If `#` is removed, the empty `href` simply hyperlinks to your current document, thereby reloading the page.

The CSS Modal example uses `#close` which may not make much sense, but it **prevents the scroll to top behaviour** by referencing it to an internal location which does not exist. Probably not the right way, but this usage points to a `preventDefault()` implemented via CSS. Thus making it a 'Pure CSS Modal'.

Here is an example.

```css
.scrollable-area {
  min-height: 150vh
}
```

```html
<span>Top of Document</span>
<div class="scrollable-area"></div>
<a href="#">Empty. Scroll to top.</a><br>
<a href="#close">Non Empty. Stay Put.</a>
```

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11246131/5496966
- [1] - [Repurposing the Hash Sign for the New Web](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/2010/11/HashInURI#introduction)

Answer (score 2):

"hash mark" is a selector (in js, css...) to point an ID, so if you have `<div id="test">` and you want to apply some functionality or some css styling with js you will select it as '#test' (the code will be different if you use jQuery framework or not). Jquery is the most used nowadays so you'll find $('#test'). **I'll try to explain how modals closing work, but first I need to explain all modal parts to put us in situation** As explanation I will use as example bootstrap's modal (as its the most used at this moment). **The modal**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

### The "Trigger" part:

To trigger the modal window, you need to use a button or a link.
Then include the two data-* attributes:

```
data-toggle="modal" opens the modal window

data-target="#myModal" points to the id of the modal
```

### The "Modal" part:

The parent `<div>` of the modal must have an ID that is the same as the value of the data-target attribute used to trigger the modal ("myModal").

The **.modal** class identifies the content of `<div>` as a modal and brings focus to it.

The **.fade** class adds a transition effect which fades the modal in and out. Remove this class if you do not want this effect.

The attribute **role="dialog"** improves accessibility for people using screen readers.

The **.modal-dialog** class sets the proper width and margin of the modal.

### The "Modal content" part:

The `<div>` with **class="modal-content"** styles the modal (border, background-color, etc.). Inside this `<div>`, add the modal's header, body, and footer.

The **.modal-header** class is used to define the style for the header of the modal. The **`<button>`** inside the header has a **data-dismiss="modal" attribute** which closes the modal if you click on it. The **.close** class styles the close button, and the **.modal-title** class styles the header with a proper line-height.

The **.modal-body** class is used to define the style for the body of the modal. Add any HTML markup here; paragraphs, images, videos, etc.

The **.modal-footer** class is used to define the style for the footer of the modal. Note that this area is right aligned by default.

### Modal Size

Change the size of the modal by adding the **.modal-sm** class for small modals or  **.modal-lg** class for large modals.

Add the size class to the `<div>` element with class **.modal-dialog**:
Small:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
```

Large:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
```

**NOTE:** To let modal at medium size let it "as is" without adding modal-* class. By default, modals are medium in size.

To resume and **answer your question**, the button with data-dismiss="modal" and the close class are readed by bootstrap's javaScript (using jQuery, but this is not relevant in that case) then changes the display:block; to display:none; and many other stylings, compare yourself:

**Opened modal:**

```
bottom:0px;
box-sizing:border-box;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display:block;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
height:89px;
left:0px;
line-height:20px;
opacity:1;
outline-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
outline-style:none;
outline-width:0px;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
padding-left:17px;
position:fixed;
right:0px;
top:0px;
transition-delay:0s;
transition-duration:0.15s;
transition-property:opacity;
transition-timing-function:linear;
width:1329px;
z-index:1050;
```

**Closed modal:**

```
bottom:0px;
box-sizing:border-box;
color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
display:none; /* changed */
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
height:auto;  /* changed */
left:0px;
line-height:20px;
opacity:0;  /* changed */
outline-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
outline-style:none;
outline-width:0px;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
position:fixed;
right:0px;
top:0px;
transition-delay:0s;
transition-duration:0.15s;
transition-property:opacity;
transition-timing-function:linear;
width:auto;  /* changed */
z-index:1050;
```

> **Note** that others like padding-left disappeared.

This can be reached simply using jQuery as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#CloseButtonID').click(){
         $('#modalID').css('display','none');
         $('#modalID').css('opacity', 0);
     }
</script>
```

**In your case,** using simply css3 modal, the fact is on modalDialog, when is on :target state it changes opacity:0 to opacity:1. **How?**
When you click on `<a href="#openModal">` the target points to `<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">` (note that # points to an ID), so modalDialog changes to modalDialog:target.

**And what about closing the modal?**
When you click on `<a href="#">` the target goes to # (when # is used single on href means the same page where you are) so it makes modalDialog loose the :target and comes back to opacity: 0;

Answer (score 2):

First, to clarify:

> The :target pseudo-class is used to style an element that is the
>   target of an internal link in a document.

This element is not on any focus state, it is just the target of an internal link.

---

Basically, the `#` represents a fragment identifier within a HTML Object. It follows the URL of the whole object, that's why the `#` is needed as a separation.

> The fragment identifier at the end of the URI is also known as the
>   “hash” of the URL.

---

So, the real question...

### What happens if you do not declare the hash?

When the fragment id is not present or void, the **target** is now the whole object. Meaning the target is now your whole HTML document.

You can see this behavior when you close your modal, it will jump all the way to the top of your document to your `<html>` tag.

See this here after scrolling:

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}
a:first-of-type {
  position: fixed;
}
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box</h2>
    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

On a side note:

I'm working on something similar in my website, currently using two modals with pure CSS, and stumbled upon the problem that it was jumping all the way to the top, that's why I made some research. I didn't want this behavior, so what I did is I defined an id to my fixed menu and made that the fragment id of the close button.

What you can do however is define an empty element with an id right next to your opening element, so that it will not jump to the top when you close your modal.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, this modal example is wholly dependent on the [fragment identifier](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/) of the url. It is not only used to "trigger" the modal display in the first place but it is also used within the anchor link to suppress the href. The text following the `#` is irrelevant in this case and should be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

As the article explains, it uses a :target in the CSS to trigger opacity: 1; Open the box, inspect the close class and change the opacity value to see what actually happens.

Comment: Thanks. I understand how the opacity works, but I don't think it explains how the `href` works to close the box. There doesn't seem to be anything special about `#close`. I can name it anything (`#apples`) and it still closes. Just seems kind of random and sloppy to me.

Comment: It does seem like a very strange way of doing a modal. The only thing special about the `#close` is in fact the `#` which prevents the href from executing. I think the `close` part should simply be omitted for clarity.