# How to prevent page from scrolling to top after css3 modal is closed?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

So, I have some css3 popups/modals that I'm working with. I'm mostly pretty happy with the way that they work, but after the modal is closed the page scrolls back up to the top and I'm not sure why this is happening.

You can see the [behavior here](http://46.101.194.36/greentec-capital.com/index.php/about-us/impact#) Here's a snippet of the html

```
   <div class="flip">
   <div class="front">
   <img src="images/SDG_ICONS/SDG01.png" alt="No Poverty" />
   </div>
   <div class="back">
      <ul>
        <a href="#ared-no-poverty"><li>ARED</li></a>
        <a href="#agrocenta-no-poverty"><li>AgroCenta</li></a>
        <a href="#tilly-no-poverty"><li>Tilly&#39;s Farm</li></a>
      </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div id="ared-no-poverty" class="overlay">
     <div class="popup">
       <h2>ARED</h2>
       <a class="close" href="#"> &times;</a>
       <p class="popup">Some text in here</p>
</div>
```

And here's the css I'm using for the popup/modals

```
.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 2;
}
.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
img.popup{
width:150px;
height: auto;
float:left;
}
.popup p{
width:auto;
margin:0;
}
.popup p:nth-child(2){
padding-top:5px;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(88, 120, 33, 0.7); /*0,0,0*/
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

So, how can I keep the at the same scroll position as when the popup was called and what is causing the modal to scroll to the top?

Comment: Position your `popup` using absolute, not relative (and set relative to their parent so it stay in position)

Comment: Do you mean set the .overlay to relative and the .popup to absolute?

Comment: I didn't tweak any of the other positioning but this doesn't seem to work. You can see it live here http://46.101.194.36/greentec-capital.com/index.php/about-us/impact#

Comment: No, your are right, it won't, I´m sure this has to do with the `:target` pseudo ... will make a few tests to see if it is it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does "#" (hash mark, number sign) close a modal box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829556/how-does-hash-mark-number-sign-close-a-modal-box)

Comment: You could replace `#` with `#!` or a pseudo location. You should reconsider using CSS modals like this one, they tend to leave loads of unnecessary history entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem why it scrolls to top is when you close the overlay you use a sinle hash in `<a class="close" href="#"> &times;</a>`, which makes it scroll to top

<strike>To make this work you could either use script, or, if each link will have its own overlay, you can target a sibling element to make it stay when closed</strike>

Use i.e. `#close` and it will work

Src: [How does "#" (hash mark, number sign) close a modal box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829556/how-does-hash-mark-number-sign-close-a-modal-box/39559607#39559607)

---

*As a side note, [here is a post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162805/toggle-radio-input-using-css-only), that have many interesting CSS only answers that might be an option instead of the `hash making history entries` issue @AnkithAmtange mentioned*

Comment: Appreciated! I'll check this in a bit!

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Thank you ... voted to close as a dupe

Comment: That thread is quite long. Hopefully OP can dig up the answer.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange I gave a short "why/how to fix" along with a reference, made my answer a wiki and voted to close as a duplicate