# Ajax request scrolling to top in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am refreshing a div inside the web page with ajax call. But **sometimes** page is scrolling to top in chrome.

I think it is same issue: [How do I stop a web page from scrolling to the top when a link is clicked that triggers JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601933/how-do-i-stop-a-web-page-from-scrolling-to-the-top-when-a-link-is-clicked-that-t)

But putting `return false` didn't resolve my problem. My code:

```
<span class="current" id="tab-kisiler"><a class="peoples" onclick="Refresh(); return false;">Refresh</a></span>

function Refresh() {
        $.post('socket/get_online_users', {city: city}, function (data) {
            $('#random_users').html(data);
        });
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: `onclick` attribute is out of date long ago. Use jquery's [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $(".peoples").on("click",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.post('socket/get_online_users', {city: $(this).data("city") }, function (data) {
        $('#random_users').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

using

```
<span class="current" id="tab-kisiler"><a class="peoples" data-city="Chicago">Refresh</a></span>
```

and assuming there is no event handler on .current or #tab-kisiler

Also when the data is loaded into the random_users, the page may move

To stop the double click from messing up try this (not tested):

```
$(function() {
  $(".peoples").on("click",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($(this).data("active")) return;
     $(this).data("active",true);
     $.post('socket/get_online_users', {city: $(this).data("city") }, function (data) {
        $('#random_users').html(data);
        $(this).data("active",false);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code. Still same. Could you look at this? http://ribony.com/aytuncordu please press the "Kişiler" button and repeat it. http://prntscr.com/917izu

Comment: I just found this: Double click the "Kişiler" button this is sending to top too.

Comment: I did notice the issue only surfacing if you rapidly double click the button, maybe you should disable the button while loading? Also it is a good idea to keep tract if your request is still running and abort it to let the other request go or visa versa.

Comment: I disabled the button while loading. (You can check in source code Refresh() function ) but problem doesn't disappeared. Could you check again?

Comment: I do not see the jumping anymore. I also do not see the loading. Perhaps it failed loading and the code stays disabled. A  $.ajax with a `.done` might be better

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following?

```
<span class="current" id="tab-kisiler"><a class="peoples">Refresh</a></span>

$('.peoples').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.post('socket/get_online_users', {city: city}, function (data) {
        $('#random_users').html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you look at my comment in above post?