# Unnecessary scrolling to the top of the page when clicking # link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link on page `<a href="#"...` which linked with jquery function. After link was clicked the page scrolled to the top and this seems unnecessary  behavior. Is there a way to prevent scrolling?

Comment: Yes. Use `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop a web page from scrolling to the top when a link is clicked that triggers JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601933/how-do-i-stop-a-web-page-from-scrolling-to-the-top-when-a-link-is-clicked-that-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click of your button you can prevent the default action using **[preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)**:

```js
 $('a[href="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log('default action prevented');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#'>Button</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent following of `#` by selecting them and using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
$(function () {
  $('a[href="#"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this : (prevent click)

```
<a href="javascript(0)" >...</a>
```

Comment: that causes "page not found exception"

Comment: you can also use :
$("#id").click(function(){
return false;
});