# Android Webview is scrolling to the top when click on link

Tags: android, webview, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a Webview loading static html content in my app.

the problem is, **when I click on a link or an embed content** (tweet, youtube video), **the webview is scrolling back to the top**.

It looks like a JS problem as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601933/how-do-i-stop-a-web-page-from-scrolling-to-the-top-when-a-link-is-clicked-that-t)

I tried to use a NestedScrollView or some tricks with params like

`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

in a LinearLayout parent but nothing works

here's my xml :

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
      android:id="@+id/article_webview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

it will be in a **recycler view**.

**My question is :**

is there a way to prevent this behavior in the webview settings or xml ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hey Paul, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hey Paul, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

I've been having the same problem. My `WebView` was inside a `RecyclerView` too.

When I added `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on my `RecyclerView`, the problem does not happen for me anymore.

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: The WebView doesn't allow focus when using this. Input fields are not editable.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same problem. My WebView was inside a
LinearLayout.

When I added **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"** on my LinearLayout.
Issue was fixed with this changes.