# My jQuery Nav menu View Jumps when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If you look at my code pen [my code pen](https://codepen.io/lootstep/pen/vYKoVRM) and scroll down to the bottom of the page, and click a drop-down link the view jumps?

```
var nav = $('#menu > ul > li');
nav.find('li').hide();
nav.click(function () {
    nav.not(this).find('li').hide();
    $(this).find('li').slideToggle();
});

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("close").style.display = "block";
    $('#menu ul').slideToggle();
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("close").style.display = "none";
    $('#menu ul').slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop a web page from scrolling to the top when a link is clicked that triggers JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601933/how-do-i-stop-a-web-page-from-scrolling-to-the-top-when-a-link-is-clicked-that-t)

Comment: can you please give me the solution I don't know jQuery

Comment: there are many solutions on the link that don't require jquery. please put some effort into reading small chunk of text. In fact, your issue is not related to jquery at all

Comment: sorry I Found it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update to your code:

```
//...
nav.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nav.not(this).find('li').hide();
    $(this).find('li').slideToggle();
});
//...
```

Explanation: you have to pass the self reference and use the `preventDetault()` method to override the default behavior.